# Where do I put java programs (SeleniumRC in my case)

Tags: executable, unzip

I've downloaded the package.  The instruction say to unzip and place in your desired directory.

What should that directory be?

Nautilus is not letting me paste it into any /opt or /usr folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand Selenium RC is run from the terminal with:

```
java -jar selenium-java-<version>.jar
```

So you can save it in whatever folder is convenient for you. You could just leave it in your home folder or make a java folder in your home folder to save other jars in. Wherever you save it you'll have to navigate to with cd or type the absolute path (e.g. ~/java/selenium-java-.jar), so put it somewhere with a nice path.